# афинные преобразования для крайних точек лица cv2

Tags: python, opencv

есть 4 набора крайних точек 4 лиц, который выдаёт MC Face API. Нужно одно лицо сравнить с 3 другими и найти из этих 3 лицо, принадлежащее человеку с первым набором. Перед этим для всех лиц нужно применить афинные преобразования, я думаю, с помощью cv2.transform. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как составить матрицу преобразования. Хочу спросить, по какому принципу её сделать, чтобы лица преобразовывались должным образом.

Comment: под лицами имеются ввиду наборы крайних точек

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю Вашу задачу -  нужно сопоставить два набора точек.

Для этого в OpenCV есть функция [estimateRigidTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform), которая находит аффинное преобразование, которое наилучшим образом совмещает точки.

Comment: мне нужно не совместить точки, а все их преобразовать так, чтобы можно было определять, одинаковые лица, или нет, дело в том, что наборы точек взяты с фото, на которых люди смотрят в разные стороны, и эти точки нужно развернуть так, чтобы, например, линия глаз была параллельна линии уголков рта и координатному вектору

Comment: Угу. Есть ключевые точки для образцового лица анфас. При сравнении ключевых точек произвольно повернутого лица найдётся такое преобразование, чтобы при его применении это лицо "выпрямилось". Меня смущает только - не исказится ли пропорция горизонталь-вертикаль?

Comment: не очень понятно про ключевые точки образцового лица, ведь у всех людей в анфас точки разные, и идти нужно к ним